# Existence of point with high curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

When working on an exercise, I stumbled upon the following "intuitive fact" which I couldn't prove:

Let $\alpha, \beta:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be two smooth curves with $\alpha(s) = \lambda(s)\beta(s)$ where $\lambda(s) \geq 1$ and $\lambda(a) = \lambda(b) = 1$. The trace of $\alpha$ is an arc of a circle of radius $r$. The tangent vectors of both cuves coincide at the ends of the domain.

**Conjecture**: There exists a point $s\in[a, b]$ with curvature $\kappa_{\beta}(s) \geq \frac{1}{r}$

The intuition is that $\beta$ has to "bend" more in order to get to the same point.

**My attempt**

I was trying to use an angular function for the curve $\beta$, $\theta'(s) = \kappa_{\beta}(s)$ since it traslates to $\theta(a) - \theta(b) = $"*measure of the arc described by $\alpha$*", and seems to relate both givens and the curvature which I'm trying to bound. However, the inequalities come out the other way, giving me an upper bound instead of a lower bound, which is a clear sign that there's some property that I'm not exploiting.

[image: The scenario]

**Edit**:

1. In my exercise, the curvature of $\beta$ does not vanish. Use that hypothesis to show the result if necessary.
2. As pointed out in the comments, degenerate cases are avoided with a little stronger but still reasonable condition that I've added in the statement. For example, in my exercise the curve $\beta$ is also simple.

Comment: What if $\beta$ is a circle with bigger radius $2r$ that goes through $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(b)$? Then the curvature is $\kappa_\beta(s)= 1/(2r) < 1/r$ everywhere. Maybe you also want to add the constraints $\beta'(a)=\alpha'(a)$ and $\beta'(b)=\alpha'(b)$?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot say that it is equal to $\frac{1}{2r}$ everywhere. In that example (or, i'm not getting your example). How do you prove that it is less than $\frac{1}{r}$ *everywhere*?

Comment: Indeed @Ernie060, the tangent vectors of both curves coincide at those points.

Comment: Well, a circle of radius $2r$ has curvature $1/(2r)$ everywhere, and that is smaller then 1/r. But you just mentioned that the tangent vectors must agree, so in that case the circle doesn't count as a counter-example anymore.

Comment: Yes, but then $\beta$ has to curve in order to coincide with $\alpha$ at the endpoints. It seems that those intervals where $\beta$ goes from the circle of radius $2r$ to the circle of radius $r$ are intervals with high curvature. I'm not saying that your example does not work, It's that I just cant see how is it less than $r$ everywhere.

Comment: If $\beta$ is a circle of radius $R$, then its curvature is constant $1/R$. $\alpha$ is also a circle thus $1/r$ is the curvature of $\alpha$ and also constant. Now, if $r < R$, then $\kappa_\beta = 1/R < 1/r = \kappa_\alpha$. It's just that.

Comment: @Ernie060, neither $\alpha(a) = \beta(a)$ nor $T_{\alpha}(a) = T_{\beta}(a)$ ($T$ is the tangent vector) nor their equivalents in $b$ are satisfied in your example.

Comment: Thank you @Ernie060, however I can't see how your example works.

Comment: I think the problem why your intuition does not apply is because your assumptions do not seem to exclude the possibility that the trace of $\beta$ goes around the whole circle and then crrosses itself to "return" and hit the second point on the circle tangentially. This seems to provide a counterexample to me. Probably you could try to assume that $\beta(s)=\lambda(s)\alpha(s)$ where $\lambda(s)\geq 1$, $\lambda(a)=\lambda(b)=1$ but $\lambda$ is not identically $1$. This seems to be what you are actually thinking about.

Comment: Yes, indeed in my problem that's the case.